# In a List of Lists, Append all Lists together into one List

Tags: prolog

I need to write a predicate `partition/2` such that `partition(L, P)` is satisfied when the concatenation of every List in the List of Lists `P` is the same as list `L`. The List of Lists `P` can contain an arbitrary number of Lists.

Example queries:

```
? - partition ([1 ,2 ,3] , P ).
P = [[1] , [2] , [3]];
P = [[1] , [2 , 3]];
P = [[1 , 2] , [3]];
P = [[1 , 2 , 3]];
no
? - partition (L , [[1] ,[2] ,[3 ,4 ,5]]).
L = [1 , 2 , 3 , 4 , 5];
no
```

I tried concatenating the lists in `P` together then checking to see if it is equal to `L`. This is what I have so far but it doesn't work. It loops indefinitely for any `P` that contains more than 1 list.

```
partition([], []).  ;; Partition of empty list is the empty list
partition(L, [L]).  ;; Base case where if P contains 1 element (list), L is equal to this list.
partition(L, [X|[Y1|Y2]]) :-
   append(X, Y1, XY1),
   partition(L, [XY1|Y2]). ;; Append each list in P to the list after it, repeating until one list is created. X is the head of the list, Y1 is the second element, and Y2 is the rest of the list.
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

The tricky part of this is to use `append/3` in a way that universally terminates.

Let's code `list_sublists/2` (a somewhat more declarative name than `partition`):

```
list_sublists([],[]).
list_sublists([X|Xs],[[Y|Ys]|Yss]) :-
    append([Y|Ys],Xs0,[X|Xs]),
    list_sublists(Xs0,Yss).
```

Consider the goal `append([Y|Ys],Xs0,[X|Xs])` in the second clause: it terminates universally when either `[Y|Ys]` or `[X|Xs]` (or both) are/is bounded in length.

Now let's run the queries you gave:

```
?- list_sublists([1,2,3],Pss).
Pss = [[1],[2],[3]] ;
Pss = [[1],[2,3]]   ;
Pss = [[1,2],[3]]   ;
Pss = [[1,2,3]]     ;
false.

?- list_sublists(Ls,[[1],[2],[3,4,5]]).
Ls = [1,2,3,4,5].
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried to minimally correct your code: it ends up to something very similar (identical, really) to @repeat answer (+1), of course

```
partition([], []).  % Partition of empty list is the empty list
%partition(L, [L]).  % Base case where if P contains 1 element (list), L is equal to this list.
% Append each list in P to the list after it, repeating until one list is created. X is the head of the list, Y1 is the second element, and Y2 is the rest of the list.
partition(L, [[X|Xs]|Zs]) :-
    append([X|Xs], Ys, L),
    partition(Ys, Zs).
```

I would say the trick it's forcing the first argument of append/3 to have length > 0, accomplished giving it the pattern `[X|Xs]` instead of simply `Xs`